# How to enhance list of accounts for the Truffle tests to run against Ropsten testnet

Tags: solidity, testrpc, testnets, truffle-test

I am working on the my contracts testing scripts. But I want to run tests not on the local TestRPC or Ganache but in the Ropsten testnet. How can I predefine a list of accounts (private keys and addresses)?

Comment: What node are you connecting to Ropsten with?

Comment: @goodvibration basically I am working with Shasta and TRON now. There no such big community for TRON, so I asked here and want to port solution to the Tronbox+tronweb+Shasta stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `truffle-hdwallet-provider` and provide it with mnemonic which has addresses funded with Ropsten Ethers.

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var mnemonic = "mountains supernatural bird ...";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      // must be a thunk, otherwise truffle commands may hang in CI
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/"),
      network_id: '3',
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Here is a real life example https://github.com/miohtama/viral-aave-save-game/blob/master/truffle-config.js#L17

Answer (score 5):

You can use HDWalletProvider to connect to a provider (infura or your local node) using a mnemonic phrase. In case you are using truffle, you can do it by seting you config to something like this:

```
...
    networks: {
    kovan: {
          provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://kovan.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`),
          network_id: 3,       // Ropsten id
          ...
        }
      }
    ...
```

Attention that [HDWalletProvider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider) is deprecated. But I, personally, still use it often for testing environments.

Comment: It is not deprecated, it was renamed/moved to truffle's monorepo. The current package is at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider.

Comment: I know you are right .. it has been renamed. But this specific repo(https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider)  is, citing, "deprecated".

Comment: The message says the "repo" is deprecated, that repo doesn't have the most recent version. It was moved inside truffle's monorepo https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider. If you follow npm instructions you should get the most recent version `npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider`.